# Android - Creating Spinner Error Message

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

So I have a form in my app to register a client. In that form I have a `Consent` drop down which has `Yes` or `No`. What I wanted to do is if the person selects `No` then they can't complete the registration, they have to select `Yes` for them to proceed to the next Activity. With my code, regardless of what the user selects it stills gives the error message and won't allow them to move on.

The code I used for this is:

**Array Adapter Set up:**

```
//set up for consent spinner
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.Register_array_consent, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mspinnerPatientConsent.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Spinner Error Set Up:**

```
// Consent Spinner Error set up
    Boolean no_error;
    TextView errorText = (TextView)mspinnerPatientConsent.getSelectedView();
    if (mspinnerPatientConsent.getSelectedItem().toString().contains("No"));{
        errorText.setText("Patient Must Consent to Be Registered");
        errorText.setError("");
    }
    if (mspinnerPatientConsent.getSelectedItem().toString().contains(" "));{
        errorText.setText("Patient Must Consent to Be Registered");
        errorText.setError("");
        no_error = false;
    }
```

*I am really new so that is probably why I can't see the problem*. I appreciate any helpful input. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

instead of using the selected item string Use

```
mspinnerPatientConsent.getSelectedItemPosition()
```

this will return the index of selected item.

```
if (mspinnerPatientConsent.getSelectedItemPosition()==0);{
    errorText.setText("Patient Must Consent to Be Registered");
    errorText.setError("");
}
if (mspinnerPatientConsent.getSelectedItemPosition()==1);{
    errorText.setText("Patient Must Consent to Be Registered");
    errorText.setError("");
    no_error = false;
}
```

Comment: Should I change this in the `if` statements too?

Comment: this code should be in the if statement,see my edited answer.

Comment: It didn't work, still gave me an error regardless of the selection